# Magento 1.9. - Third party payment gateway

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, payment-gateway

For our Magento website, we currently have no payment methods enabled.  It is generated an email in our system.
However, we would now like for customers to be able to pay with their credit cards. For that, we would like to use a third-party solution.

We have Magento version 1.9.3.2.

I'm looking for a possible solution. Any recommendations on what works well?

Answer (score 0):

By Default Magento support [Paypal](https://www.paypal.com/us/home) - that supports **Credit card** & **Debit card** , you can configure paypal from backend with help of below links....

https://www.paypal.com/us/selfhelp/article/how-do-i-integrate-paypal-payments-standard-with-magento-community-edition-1.7.x-1.9.x-ts1524

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/magento/magento_setup_paypal_payment.htm

http://www.harapartners.com/blog/magento-paypal-integration/

https://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/paypal

Answer (score 0):

You can also go with  Braintree, Stripe , Authorize.Net

For Authorize.Net - Refer http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/payment/authorize-net-setup.html

For Stripe - https://stripe.com/docs/currencies

Comment: Thank you.
Stripe seems to very interesting. Any experiences with it? Setting it up?

Comment: yes, i have also configure stripe in our projects , its also easy to impliments with its wonderfull api in magento , you can use its extension from magento or github site. feel free for ask more details